# Cannot convert array of bytes to string

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, encoding

I have the code below:

```
Dim base64Decoded As String
Dim base64Encoded As String = "aGVsbG8="
Dim data As Byte()
data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64Encoded)
base64Decoded = System.Convert.FromBase64String(data)
MsgBox(base64Decoded)
```

However, I'm getting an error message at the `base64Decoded = ...` line:

> Value of type 'Byte()' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like you didn't get your informed badge until know, just feel free to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/Tour) to learn more about Stackoverflow: *Upvoting, accepting answers, asking good questions,...* and to get your informed badge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to convert this string to an array of bytes using `System.Convert.FromBase64String` then convert it to String using `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString` , `FromBase64String` take a string as parameter. Just try the following:

```
base64Decoded = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded))
```

in your case `aGVsbG8=` will be converted to:

> hello

**Reference**

- [ASCIIEncoding.GetString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Convert.FromBase64String Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @AndrewMorton i fixed the error, now it is working. Thx for the remark